# Can i update an existing log entry using NLog?

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I am writing a windows service, that logs quite a few entries using NLog.
However when it starts logging errors (perhaps due to a longer internet outage), it is not relevant to log the same error every 10th or so seconds.
So I tried to look for a way to update an existing log entry, using NLog, as it is familiar to me. - But to no avail...

Does anyone know of a way to update a single entry of a log, without rewriting the entirety of the file?

The program is on a server, and writes to a local .txt file. Currently using NLog, but i am not sure if it is even possible with NLog. I have not been able to find anything on it.

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: You should improve your logging strategy. Manipulating logs after they are written is not a good idea. You can configure your logging framework (like NLOG) to write in multiple log-files depending on LogLevels, like logging errors in a separate file

Comment: Something for NLog ver. 4.5 https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/WhenRepeated-Filter maybe combined with https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/PostFilteringWrapper-target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Jehof. Ideally, logging is append only.

As an alternative; you could potentially write your own custom NLog wrapper that filters duplicate log attempts within a timespan.
see https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Targets-and-Wrappers for more information about NLog wrappers.

This [blog](http://www.michaelwilliams.co.za/5-minute-nlog-wrapper-limiting-the-number-of-emails-sent/) shows an example about how to write a NLog wrapper. Although the NLog wrapper in this example does not fit your exact scenario, you could probably use it as a baseline for your implementation...